# What is the "reference tick" field of a data shred?

Tags: shred

The Solana data shred header contains a 8-bit `flags` field (offset `0x55`).

The content of flags is defined as a bitfield with 3 members.

```
bitflags! {
    #[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize)]
    pub struct ShredFlags:u8 {
        const SHRED_TICK_REFERENCE_MASK = 0b0011_1111;
        const DATA_COMPLETE_SHRED       = 0b0100_0000;
        const LAST_SHRED_IN_SLOT        = 0b1100_0000;
    }
}
```

The "reference tick" for data shreds is defined as the value of `flags & SHRED_TICK_REFERENCE_MASK`.
This results in an integer in `[0;64)`.

What is the definition of this field?

Do coding shreds have a "reference tick"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the definition of this field?

The reference tick indicates the tick height a leader was at within their slot when they converted a given set of entries (sets of transactions) to shreds for broadcast across the cluster. [This snippet](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/b8e25282c27c42cc660de93622f379e3944830ca/core/src/broadcast_stage/standard_broadcast_run.rs#L233-L235) shows this in action:

```
        // 2) Convert entries to shreds and coding shreds
        let is_last_in_slot = last_tick_height == bank.max_tick_height();
        let reference_tick = bank.tick_height() % bank.ticks_per_slot();
        let (data_shreds, coding_shreds) = self.entries_to_shreds(
```

> This results in an integer in [0;64).

This gives us just enough space as the clusters have 64 ticks per slot (this value can be queried from genesis config).

> Do coding shreds have a "reference tick"?

No, coding shreds don't have a reference tick as their sole purpose is to recover missing data shreds. In the same file that you found `ShredFlags`, you can see the contents of the [headers for both data and coding shreds](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/b8e25282c27c42cc660de93622f379e3944830ca/core/src/broadcast_stage/standard_broadcast_run.rs#L233-L235), noting that `ShredFlags` are only present in `DataShredHeader`:

```
/// The data shred header has parent offset and flags
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct DataShredHeader {
    parent_offset: u16,
    flags: ShredFlags,
    size: u16, // common shred header + data shred header + data
}

/// The coding shred header has FEC information
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct CodingShredHeader {
    num_data_shreds: u16,
    num_coding_shreds: u16,
    position: u16, // [0..num_coding_shreds)
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- Does the tuple (shred_version, slot, parent_offset, reference_tick) uniquely identify a set of entries assuming no duplicate blocks? So that this set can be deshredded out-of-order if the lower shred index bound of the set is known?
(EDIT: out-of-order as in, being able to deshred a set of entries without having deshredded the predecessor set within the same block)